# Не выполняется запрос в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма, в форме логин, емайл, сообщение. После введения обработчик делает свою работу, но в БД ничего не заносит. Но, если вывести переменный на экран, они отображаются. Такой же запрос, но с другими значениями прекрасно работает на другой странице. В чём проблема?

В БД поля : `ID(ai)`, `FROM`, `MESSAGE`, `EMAIL`, `WHOM`.

Код:

```
<?php

    $from = trim($from);
    $ban_email = trim($ban_email);
    $text_banned = trim($text_banned);
    echo $from ,$ban_email,$text_banned ;
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT  INTO messages (from,message,whom,email) VALUES ('$from','$text_banned','$from','$ban_email')");
?>
```

Comment: К бд инклудится

Comment: Методом POST отправляется

Comment: вот так написать, религия не позволяет ?
посмотрим, что скажет die:

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT  INTO messages (from,message,whom,email) VALUES ('$from','$text_banned','$from','$ban_email')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,message,whom,email) VALUES ('Login','Message','Login','Email')' at line 1

Comment: думаЮ, что не нравиться `from` ([не буду обяснять где оно обычно используеться][1])


  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сколько ж вас учить то нужно

```
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT  INTO messages (from,message,whom,email) VALUES ('".$from.",'".$text_banned."','".$from."','".$ban_email."')"); // кавычки
```

Кавычки при запросе ставьте, не ленитесь!!!

Answer (score 0):

Имена полей надо ставить в `` , а значения в ' '