# Почему не работает update?

Tags: jquery, php, mysql

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой: не работает команда Update.

Что происходит: javascript отправляет ряд переменных в файл-обработчик, в обработчике их принимаем.

```
if (isset($_POST['window_id'])) {
    $window_id = $_POST['window_id'];
    if ($window_id == '') {
        unset($window_id);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['left'])) {
    $left = $_POST['left'];
    if ($left == '') {
        unset($left);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['top'])) {
    $top = $_POST['top'];
    if ($top == '') {
        unset($top);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['width'])) {
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    if ($width == '') {
        unset($width);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['height'])) {
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    if ($height == '') {
        unset($height);
    }
}
```

Что происходит дальше. Идет ряд условий

```
if (isset($id) and $id != '') {
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM windows WHERE uid='$id' AND window_id ='$window_id'", $db);
    $myrow3  = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

    if ($result3 != TRUE) {
        $result4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO windows (uid,window_id,left,top,width,height) VALUES ('$id','$window_id','$left','$top','$width','$height')", $db);

    } else {
        $result5 = mysql_query("UPDATE windows SET left = '$left', top = '$top', width = '$width', height = '$height' WHERE window_id = '$window_id'", $db);

        if ($result5 == TRUE) {
            echo "Все должно сработать";
        }        
    }
}
```

Но запрос

```
 $result5 = mysql_query("UPDATE windows SET left = '$left', top = '$top', width = '$width', height = '$height' WHERE window_id = '$window_id'",$db);
```

не срабатывает, не могу разобраться, в чем проблема. Условие

```
if (isset($id) and $id != '')
```

работает. Условие

```
 if($result3 != TRUE)
```

тоже работает. Ну и для полного полотна привожу дамп таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `windows` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `window_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `left` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `top` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `windows` (`id`, `uid`, `window_id`, `left`, `top`, `width`, `height`) VALUES
(2, 1, 'okno', 405, 182, 713, 383);
```

Comment: Вот такую ошибку он вываливает
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left = '442', top = '63', width = '713', height = '383' WHERE uid = '1' AND wind' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Ужас, просто ужас

Неустанные тренировки для меня просто сегодня, одни и те же вопросы.

```
 $result5 = mysql_query("UPDATE windows SET left = '".$left."', top = '".$top."', width = '".$width."', height = '".$height."' WHERE window_id = '".$window_id."'",$db);
```

Неужели так сложно воспользоваться поиском и прочитать ответ, на [идентичный просто идентичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130342/)

Нет ну если

```
if($result3 != TRUE)
тоже работает.
```

Значит незачем условию выполнять **$result5**

Comment: Нет эта запись тоже не работает

Comment: Все разобрался заработало

Comment: пришлось название переменных поменять а так же название полей таблици

Answer (score 0):

Поле с автоикрементом нельзя задавать в операторе `INSERT`.

Comment: Это дамп таблицы созданный автоматически через phpmyadmin